# MongoDB query using values priority

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following documents in my collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d11f213c27c35395fd3"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "state" : "OH",
    "code" : "CDM"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d29f213c27c35395fe0"),
    "name" : "Test1",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "CDM"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d38f213c27c35395fe7"),
    "name" : "Test2",
    "state" : "OH",
    "code" : "ALL"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d46f213c27c35395feb"),
    "name" : "Test3",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "ALL"
}
```

Trying to filter documents based on `state` and `code`.

But there are few criteria if particular `state` or `code` is not found then search with value `ALL`

Example 1:

state = CA

code = CDM

then return only

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d29f213c27c35395fe0"),
    "name" : "Test1",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "CDM"
}
```

Example 2:

state = CA

code = DCM

then return only

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d46f213c27c35395feb"),
    "name" : "Test3",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "ALL"
}
```

etc..

The query that i tried was state = CA ,code = CDM:

```
db.getCollection('user_details').aggregate([

{'$match': { 'state': {'$in': ['CA','ALL']},
'code': {'$in': ['CDM','ALL']}}}

])
```

return was:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d29f213c27c35395fe0"),
    "name" : "Test1",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "CDM"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d46f213c27c35395feb"),
    "name" : "Test3",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "ALL"
}
```

Expected was :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d29f213c27c35395fe0"),
        "name" : "Test1",
        "state" : "ALL",
        "code" : "CDM"
    }
```

Could you help to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you've to return `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d46f213c27c35395feb"),
    "name" : "Test3",
    "state" : "ALL",
    "code" : "ALL"
}` if both are not found ?

Comment: @whoami   yes......

Comment: Also if you've both `{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d29f213c27c35395fe0"),
        "name" : "Test1",
        "state" : "ALL",
        "code" : "CDM"
    }` & `{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea32d29f213c27c35395fe1"),
        "name" : "Test2",
        "state" : "CA",
        "code" : "CDM"
    }` then what has to be returned - Only the 2nd Doc ?

Comment: Second one ( when state = CA , code = CDM )

Comment: *no document should be returned* ? Ok this is weird (Please edit the question for those scenarios) - with all these complications you can better opt to do it in code offloading stress on DB, Meanwhile you can try this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/ejx5TCZyNEr)

Comment: Updated the comment

Answer (score 1):

Try below query :

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      state: "CA",
      code: "CDM"
    },
    {
      state: "ALL",
      code: "CDM"
    },
    {
      state: "ALL",
      code: "ALL"
    },
    {
      state: "CA",
      code: "ALL"
    }
  ]
})
```

So basically you can not achieve what you're looking for in one query, you can try aggregation operator [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) & [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) to do this but I would not prefer to do that cause each stage in facet will do the given operation on entire collection's data. Instead get fewer docs using above query & in your code you can actually filter for best suited doc, Which would be easy & efficient. Don't forget to maintain [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/index.html) on DB.

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JnBdSrzFtYK)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.user_details.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      match: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $or: [
              {
                "state": "CA",
                "code": {
                  "$in": [ "CDM", "ALL" ]
                }
              },
              {
                "state": {
                  "$in": [ "CA", "ALL"]
                },
                "code": "CDM"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      all: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "state": "ALL",
            code: "ALL"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      match: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [ { $size: "$match" },  0]
          },
          "$all",
          "$match"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$match"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$match"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vhKYcoVeBYw)